# Using "expanding characters" in a variable in a bash script

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I apologize beforehand for this question, which is probably both ill formulated and answered a thousand times over. I get the feeling that my inability to find an answer is that I don't quite know how to ask the question.

I'm writing a script that traverses folders in a bunch of mounted external hard drives, like so:

`for g in /Volumes/compartment-?/{Private/Daniel,Daniel}/Projects/*/*`

It then proceeds to perform long-running tasks on each of the directories found there. Because these operations are io-intensive rather than cpu-intensive, I thought I'd add the option to provide which "compartment" I want to work in, so that I can parallelize the workloads.

But, doing

```
cmp="?"
[[ ! "$1" = "" ]] && cmp="$1"
```

And then,
`for g in /Volumes/compartment-$cmp/{Private/Daniel,Daniel}/Projects/*/*`

Doesn't work - the question mark that should expand to all compartments instead becomes literal, so I get an error that "compartment-?" doesn't exist, which is of course true.

How do I create a variable with a value that "expands," like `dir="./*"` working with `ls $dir`?

EDIT: Thanks to @dan for the answer. I was brought up to be courteous and thank people, so I did thank him for it in a comment on his question, but that comment has been removed, and I'm anxious that repeating it might be some kind of infraction here. I ended up simply escaping my question mark glob character, i.e. `\?`, since for this script I only need to either search all drives or one particular drive. But I'll keep the answer handy for the next time I write a script where I'd like to support more advanced arguments.

Comment: You didn't quote so $cmp expanding to ? should also help expand the words with filename expansion. Also mind that brace expansion happens before variable expansion so you can't assign brace expressions in the variable.  Also check if you have `set -f` or `noglob` enabled on your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace expansion occurs *before* variable expansion. Pathname/glob expansion (eg `?`, `*`) occurs last. Therefore you can't use the glob character `?` in a variable, and in a brace expansion.

You *can* use a glob expression in an unquoted variable, without brace expansion. Eg. `q=\?; echo compartment-$q` is equivalent to `echo compartment-?`.

To solve your problem, you could define an array based on the input argument:

```
if [[ $1 ]]; then
    [[ -d /Volumes/compartment-$1 ]] || exit 1
    files=("/Volumes/compartment-$1"/{Private/Daniel,Daniel}/Projects/*/*)
else
    files=(/Volumes/compartment-?/{Private/Daniel,Daniel}/Projects/*/*)
fi

# then iterate the list:
for i in "${files[@]}"; do
...
```

Another option is a nested loop. The path expression in the outer loop doesn't use brace expansion, so (unlike the first example) it can expand a glob in `$1` (or default to `?` if `$1` is empty):

```
for i in /Volumes/compartments-${1:-?}; do
    [[ -d $i ]] &&
    for j in {Private/Daniel,Daniel}/Projects/*/*; do
        [[ -e $j ]] || continue
        ...
```

- Note that the second example expands a glob expression passed in `$1` (eg. `./script '[1-9]'`). The first example does not.
- Remember that pathname expansion has the property of expanding only to existing files, or literally. `shopt -s nullglob` guarantees expansion only to existing files (or nothing).
- You should either use nullglob, or check that each file or directory exists, like in the examples above.
- Using `$1` unquoted also subjects it to word splitting on whitespace. You can set `IFS=` (empty) to avoid this.